# php fetch array after mysql union

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, union, fetch

What is the problem of this mysql syntax? I copied it to phpmyadmin and it worked flawlessly. When I tried to fetch the array from php but it returned a "bool(false)" error.

```
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        cim, 
        'news' as kat 
    FROM 
        mbsz_news 
    WHERE 
        cim LIKE '%anystring%' 
        OR lead LIKE '%anystring%' 
        OR content LIKE '%anystring%'
) 
UNION 
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        p_name, 
        'plaza' as kat 
    FROM 
        mbsz_plazas 
    WHERE 
        p_name LIKE '%anystring%' 
        OR uzemelteto LIKE '%anystring%'
) 
UNION 
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        cim, 
        'book' as kat 
    FROM 
        mbsz_konyvtar 
    WHERE 
        cim LIKE '%anystring%' 
        OR kszam LIKE '%anystring%' 
        OR kiado LIKE '%anystring%'
)
```

PHP code:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo $row['type'];
}
```

`$res` gives the error bool(false)
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are there brackets around your query?

Comment: The syntax looks okay (Your union column names aren't the same, but as long as the column types are the same, they should take the first query's names/aliases) - so it probably comes down to your PHP code.

Comment: Does `mysql_error()` return anything? If not, it's not a mysql error. Either no results or a PHP error.

Comment: The PHP code:
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res));
    {
        echo $row['type'];
    }

Not working, for $res, gives the error bool(false).

Comment: You have a `;` after your while??

Comment: Have you confirmed that your connection is set up properly?

Comment: no it was just a typo :)

Comment: can you post the table structure, with sample data?

Comment: Check for errors `mysql_error()`!

Comment: found the problem, in phpmyadmin, with brackets the sql syntax works, but in php, didn't... So this was the answer. :)

Comment: @GaborKocsis Well, that's pretty weird. As a test, I created a simple table and ran a mysql statement with two unions and 3 selects, surrounding each select statement with parenthesis just like you had. The selects were just querying the same table, but it worked fine from PHP. I am using PHP 5.3.10 and Mysql 5.5.24.

Answer (score 0):

you must declare the sql variable. e.g.

```
$sql = (
    (SELECT 
        id, 
        cim, 
        'news' as kat 
    FROM 
        mbsz_news 
    WHERE 
        cim LIKE '%anystring%' 
        OR lead LIKE '%anystring%' 
        OR content LIKE '%anystring%'
) 
UNION 
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        p_name, 
        'plaza' as kat 
    FROM 
        mbsz_plazas 
    WHERE 
        p_name LIKE '%anystring%' 
        OR uzemelteto LIKE '%anystring%'
) 
UNION 
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        cim, 
        'book' as kat 
    FROM 
        mbsz_konyvtar 
    WHERE 
        cim LIKE '%anystring%' 
        OR kszam LIKE '%anystring%' 
        OR kiado LIKE '%anystring%'
)
```

)

when the variable is called, the php should work?

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo $row['type'];
}
```